# Nodered Losing nodes on rpi

Tags: raspbian, nodered

After installing nodes (eg npm install --unsafe-perm node-red-contrib-i2c) and restarting node-red i find them in the pallet.

after reboot (nodered start on boot) i no longer find then in the pallet tought they still appear in the fodler

where did i miss somthing?

Edit: used os is raspbian
Npm is node package manager and comes with nodered

Comment: What operating system do you use? Is it Raspbian? What does it mean: `npm install ...`? On my RasPi I get `-bash: npm: command not found`. What do you mean when you write: "*i no longer find then in the pallet tought they still appear in the fodler*"?

Comment: Raspbian is used. Npm is the node package manager. When installed all is fine. After reboot the nodes are no longer visible in the nodered program